# Gesturedetector and registerForContextMenu

Tags: android, gesturedetector, onfling, android-contextmenu

I am turning insane over here trying to understand why i find nothing about this and why it does not work.

I am using an onFling to do some actions. Working perfectly. 
But i would like to add an onlongpress which would open a context menu.
The onlongpress toasts works perfectly too. But the issue comes when i try to do a registerForContextMenu.
If i give my linearlayout, or any of my elements in the view, the onlongpress makes the contextmenu show up, but my onfling doesnt work anymore (at all).

So i tried to only registerForContextMenu onlongpress, and then unregisterforcontextmenu (yes, that one exist, yes i didnt tought it would work like that either :o)) but that does not work.

So, any ideas why the "registerForContextMenu" makes the onfling stop?

Please tell me if you need a part of the code.

Regards
H

edit;

in my oncreate i call:
registerForContextMenu(ivMain);  //this is an imageview

gDetect = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());

my gesture listener:

```
public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

        super.onLongPress(e);
        openContextMenu(ivMain);//my imageview i used registerForContextMenu
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        // calculate the change in X position within the fling gesture
        float horizontalDiff = event2.getX() - event1.getX();
        // calculate the change in Y position within the fling gesture
        float verticalDiff = event2.getY() - event1.getY();
        float absHDiff = Math.abs(horizontalDiff);
        float absVDiff = Math.abs(verticalDiff);
        float absVelocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
        // float absVelocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);

        if (absHDiff > absVDiff && absHDiff > flingMin && absVelocityX > velocityMin) {
            // move forward or backward
            if (horizontalDiff < 0) {
                stuff();
                    return true;
                }

            } else {
                otherstuff();
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you call your detector?

Comment: Hi. In my onCreate i do a gDetect = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());

Comment: where do you  call gDetect.onTouchEvent()?

Comment: after my oncreate function with '@Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  this.gDetect.onTouchEvent(event);
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
 }'

Comment: what is onTouchEvent?  is it View or Activity method?

Comment: it says its override the ontouchevent in activity (this came from a tutorial earlier today)

Comment: try view.setOnTouchListener and call your detector here

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean (starting with programming). What should i set "view" to?

Comment: try ivMain.setOnTouchListener

Comment: So, to whom should i send the cookies? :) This solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: eat them by yourself,  bon appétit

Answer (score 0):

As  pskink sugested, i needed to remove the ontouch override of the activity, and add an onclicklistener to my view and call my gesturedetector from there instead.

```
ivMain.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gDetect.onTouchEvent(event);
            //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
 }
});
```

Big thanks to pskink.